# How to make facebook permissions required in auth dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK to display the Auth-Dialog and get the user email.

```
FB.login(function(response) {
if(response.status==="connected")
{           
    //do stuff
}
else
{
  //do other stuff
}
}, {
               scope: 'email',
               auth_type: 'rerequest',
               return_scopes: true
});
```

Everything is fine but: The user has the possibility to decline the access to the email but use the app anyway.

But my App needs the email, so I want to make it required.

The facebook docs say I should check after the auth which permissons are declined and ask again.

But I saw several Facebook Auth Dialogs in the wild where the email is required and can not be declined (e.g StackExchange). Even in the Facebook App Settings I cannot take email permission back, i would have to remove the whole app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With API v2 you can not do that any more. Those apps that you saw are still using v1, but they will have to switch to v2 end of April. And no, for a new app created after API v2 was introduced, you can not “downgrade”. But since you will not _get_ an email address from Facebook for every user in any case (f.e. for those that registered using just their mobile), you need to provide them with a way to enter an email themselves if your app requires one.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. Sorry, didnt find it in the docs. And thanks for the info about the mobile users - i was aware of this problem, but I think in this case its okay to ask for the email again. But asking a user who just klicked around to declined a permission again for permission is somehow harsh. So i wantend to avoid that.